# Dictionary key and string comparison in python

Tags: python, django

I compared the dictionary key with a predefined string, eventhough it looks similar, but the comparison always fails.
for example: key='eng-101' and 'eng-101' string are not same.

please help

```
for key, value in course_dict.items() :
        print('search ky is --'+key)
        print('the elective courses are---',courses)

        #finding the key in string
        if(courses.find(key)==-1):
            print('key not found--'+key)

        else:
            print('---------------------the key found is---'+key)
            key=str(key +'-101,')
            key=key.replace(' ','')
            first_year_el_course+=key

            print(elective_counter)
            print(first_year_el_course)
            print('newly formatter key--:   '+key)

            print(key=='eng-101')
```

Comment: Question is not so clear. Please add input and  expected o/p? How the input dictionary looks and what actually you want etc.

Comment: Also, the use of **str()** is useless as already it's concatenating inside so final outcome would be a string, so explicit conversion is not needed. If you think, key is other than string then the statement should be `str(key) + '-101'` not `str(key +'-101')`.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
key=str(key +'-101,')    # Remove the comma at the end, otherwise key will be 'eng-101,' and not 'eng-101'.
```

To:

```
key = str(key) + '-101'  # Convert key to string. '-101' is already a string.
```

Comment: Also, the use of **str()** is useless as already it's concatenating inside so final outcome would be a string, so explicit conversion is not needed. If key is other than string then the statement should be `str(key) + '-101'` not `str(key +'-101')`.

Answer (score 1):

@DipenDadhaniya is correct but it is always better to use string formatting. This should make your code more concise and easy to read.

Be careful about changing the iteration variable `key` during an iteration as this can sometimes lead to unintended consequences which can be difficult to debug. Give it a new name such as `new_key`.

```py
new_key = '{}-101'.format(key.replace(' ', ''))
```

Comment: this does not answer the original question and should be posted as a comment